# Serenity... how to get the Webdriver?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I just created a sample project using Serenity + cucumber + java + maven ( > mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber) .

I can see when it brings up a firefox browser and goes to this website:

```
@DefaultUrl("http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary")
```

Question:
  From this point, a "WebDriver driver" was created, but how can I obtain/get to that "driver" variable ?  I'm trying to get the window ID using driver.getWindowHandle().

Updated:  The statements are as followed:

```
@DefaultUrl("http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary")
public class DictionaryPage extends PageObject {...}
```

I looked up the PageObject super class and found this:

```
public abstract class PageObject extends net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject {

        protected PageObject() {
        super();
    }

    protected PageObject(WebDriver driver, Predicate<? super net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject> callback) {
        super(driver, callback);
    }

    public PageObject(WebDriver driver, int ajaxTimeout) {
        super(driver, ajaxTimeout);
    }

    public PageObject(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
}
```

So.. the PageObject uses the webdriver variable from another super class.  What is the syntax I need to declare to get to this "web driver" variable?
  Thanks
  Know-nada
 =========================

JDelorean!

Thanks a lot for your help.  Here are the codes.. Would you please help tp point out what is wrong with the "driver"?

1 - Feature File:
    Feature: Amazon user login authentication
      Scenario: Amazon user login authentication
        Given user is on the "home" page

2 - Step Definitions File:
    package com.XXXX.steps;
    import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;
    import com.XXXX.steps.serenity.User;
    import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

```
 class DefinitionSteps {
    @Steps
    User user;

    @Given("^user is on the \"([^\"]*)\" page$")
    public void user_is_on_the_Amazon_page(String pageName)throws Throwable{
        user.is_on_the_page(pageName);
    }
}
```

3 - Test Runner class
    package com.XXXX;

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features")
public class DefinitionTestSuite {
```

}

4 - The User Class where I am not able to capture the driver.  Please note that at the end of this file, the commented out line is the one that does not work.  Also notice that the "driver" was set to the original driver "home.getDriver()" but somehow that value was passed to the "driver" but the driver "home.getDriver()" works just fine.

```
package com.XXXX.steps.serenity;

import com.XXXX.pages.Home;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.steps.ScenarioSteps;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class User extends ScenarioSteps{

    Home home = new Home();
    WebDriver driver = home.getDriver();

    @Step
    public void is_on_the_page(String pageName) throws Throwable {
        home.open();

home.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(home.homeElements.get("Hello. Sign in"))).click();
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[1]")).click();
    } 
}
```

Comment: this is more related to driver management. check alternate discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40130996/is-there-any-framework-which-supports-behaviour-driven-approch-bdd-for-seleniu)

Answer (score 1):

`PageObject` has a `getDriver()` method, which you should use if you require the use of `WebDriver`.

I strongly suggest you study the [Serenity BDD's Manual](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#introduction) if you are going to work with the framework. You should find an answer to most questions there. Alternatively, check [Serenity BDD Users Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/thucydides-users).

Comment: Thanks  JDeloran for guiding me the group.    I did find the `getDriver()` from the PageObject super class, then I tried to caputre that superdriver `WebDriver driver = getDriver()`in the class where it extends the PageObject superclass.  I saw no complaints.  Then when I tried to see the content of the driver by `System.out.println ("driver value +" + driver)` I got a null pointer exception.. hummmm

Comment: Make sure you have initialized the `WebDriver` in the first place. `PageObject` is not responsible for that and will not do it for you. Please edit your question and post the code where you initialize the `driver`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved following way.

```
WebDriver driver = Serenity.getDriver();
driver.findElement(By.xpath....);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, the Serenity-BDD:Cucumber framework does not allow you to assign its driver to your local variable.
  This assignment statement `WebDriver driver = getDriver();` will result in a null pointer in the "driver" local variable.
  My guess is that the framework needs to protect its `getDriver()` because it needs to do report on snapshots and scenarios steps.
  So you have it.  simply use the framework's `getDriver()` and you can drive from page to page without any  problem at all as long as you declare your page class as an extension of the base/Abstract class PageObject.
  An example of your page class:

```
public void HomePage extends PageObject {
}
```

At the time you instantiate the HomePage class `HomePage homePage;` the framework's driver is automatically attached to the `homePage`.
  Let say you want to click on an element, you simply state:

```
   getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("locationOfTheTargetElement").click();
```