# Is there any framework which supports Behaviour driven approch (bdd) for selenium-webdriver with driver managment?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium, bdd, qaf

I want to start my automation project from scratch, as per requirements I have to use Behavior Driven Approach for testcase authoring and selenium for Automation. please suggest best suited framework.

Comment: You may opt for Cucumber. It's behavior driven and open source.

Comment: There is one another nice framework [qaf](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) which provides bdd  in addition to many other selenium/webdriver specific driver management features...

Comment: @optimist_creeper : i require features like "driver management", "parallel execution" , "run configuration" and cucumber doesn't support this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check open source [QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) for web (selenium-webdriver) and mobile (appium) automation. It has all the features driver management, parallel execution, run configuration you want and many more like data-driven testing, data-bean, locator repository, integration with third party tools (CI, Test Management tools etc).

It support **BDD**, **keyword-driven** and **coded (TestNG test)** approach for authoring test cases. So you can opt bdd for test authoring.

You also will find inbuilt bdd steps ready to use for selenium webdriver and rest-webservices with the framework.

You can start by downloading [blank project](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project) from git which uses ANT and IVY. If you want to use maven you can download [qaf-blank-project-maven](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-blank-project-maven). 
For getting started follow [step-by-step-tutorial](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki)

Comment: it looks impressive and i am evaluating it